# Interpretation of gradient mapping

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have an objective function

$$f(x)=\|Ax-b\|^2, A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}, x \in \mathbb{R}^3, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

I want to use gradient mapping to minimize this function. To do so, I know that

$$x_Q(\bar{x},\gamma)=arg min[f(\bar{x}+\langle f'(\bar{x}),x-\bar{x}\rangle+\frac{\gamma}{2}\|x-\bar{x}\|^2]$$
$$g_Q(\bar{x},\gamma)=\gamma(\bar{x}-x_Q(\bar{x},\gamma)$$

My questions is about the $f'(\bar{x})$ term. When finding this term, I let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&A_{13}\\A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}\end{bmatrix}, x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}, b=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$$

From here, I know that $$f(x)=\|\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&A_{13}\\A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}\|^2 = \|\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1\\A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2\\A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3\end{bmatrix}\|^2$$

Breaking apart the magnitude:
$$\sqrt{(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)^2+(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)^2+(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)^2}^2=(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)^2+(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)^2+(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)^2$$

Then, calculating the partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=2A_{11}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)+2A_{21}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)+2A_{31}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=2A_{12}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)+2A_{22}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)+2A_{32}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}=2A_{13}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)+2A_{23}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)+2A_{33}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)$$

Combining the partials, I arrive at
$$f'(x)=\begin{bmatrix}2A_{11}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)+2A_{21}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)+2A_{31}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)\\2A_{12}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)+2A_{22}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)+2A_{32}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)\\2A_{13}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3-b_1)+2A_{23}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3-b_2)+2A_{33}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3-b_3)\end{bmatrix}$$
Can anyone verify if this is correct?

Comment: Why do you say "consequently, $f'(\bar x) = 0$"? I don't see how that follows.

Comment: I say this because the derivative of any scalar will always be zero

Comment: It's not true that the derivative of any scalar-valued function is $0$. For example, what about the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$? The output of this function is a scalar, but the derivative of $f$ is not $0$.

Comment: Wow. Yes, my brain is not functioning properly. Moving on from that ... Would the derivation simply form this basic matrix? I feel like I am still missing something. $f'(x)=$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{A_{11}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3)}{(\sqrt{A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3})^2}=A_{11}\\\frac{A_{21}(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3)}{(\sqrt{A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3})^2}=A_{21}\\\frac{A_{31}(A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3)}{(\sqrt{A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3})^2}=A_{31}\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Where do the terms in the denominator come from? Also, are you re-using the letter $A_{11}$ which has already been used for something else? We can't use the same letters for different quantities.

Comment: The terms being the index within the matrix. e.g. $A_{11}$ is the element in the first row and first column of the 3x3 matrix. $x_3$ would be the third row of a 3x1 matrix. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Maybe you could add a note to the end of your question that explains how you attempted to compute $f'(x)$, then I can see how you got the expression in your previous comment and we'll see what went wrong.

Comment: Updated the question, and found an error with my comment above anyways (: Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Cool. I don't see where the denominators come from in your expression for $f'(x)$. Maybe you could explain in a bit more detail how you computed $f'(x)$.

Comment: Well it looks like the reason you don't understand where the denominators came from, is because they shouldn't be there (: I updated the main question more, going into step by step detail for how I arrived at the final f'(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression for $f'(x)$ is correct, and it can be written concisely in matrix notation as $\nabla f(x) = 2A^T(Ax-b)$.

The formula can also be derived easily using the multivariable chain rule. Note that $f(x) =g(h(x))$, where $h(x) = Ax-b$ and $g(u) = \|u\|^2$. The derivatives of $g$ and $h$ are $g'(u) = 2u^T$ (a row vector) and $h'(x) = A$. By the chain rule, the derivative of $f$ is 
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= g'(h(x)) h'(x) \\
&= 2(Ax-b)^T A.
\end{align}
My notation differs slightly from yours because in my notation $f'(x)$ is a row vector.
If we use the convention that the gradient is a column vector, then
$$
\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = 2 A^T(Ax-b).
$$

Comment: Thank you for all the help!